# Error "Undefined offset" al cargar menú y submenú

Tags: php

Creo un menú que tiene sus propios elementos y me sale un error:

> Undefined offset: 2

¿Porqué me sale ese error?

```
$menu = array(
    1 => 'about',
    2 => 'news',
    3 => 'search',
);

$submenu = array(
    1 => array( 'about my name', 'about my location' ),
    3 => array( 'search me' ),
);

if (is_array($menu))
{
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $menu as $key=>$row )
        {
            echo '<li>'.$row.'</li>';
            if (is_array($submenu[$key]))
            {
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach( $submenu[$key] as $sub )
                {
                    echo '<li>'.$sub.'</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Resultado:

> ```
> about
> about my name
> about my location
> news
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in index.php on line 19
> search
> search me
> ```

Comment: Esto es porque $menu tiene un elemento en la llave 2, mientras que $submenu sólo tiene llaves 1 y 3. Debieras probar `if(isset($submenu[$key]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tus arrays le sobran las comas `,` al final:

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/W9rDT6)**

```
    <?php

    $menu = array(
        1 => 'about',
        2 => 'news',
        3 => 'search'
//, <- Error, no coma aquí, el array no continúa
    );

    $submenu = array(
        1 => array( 'about my name', 'about my location' ),
        3 => array( 'search me' )
//, <- Error, no coma aquí, el array no continúa

    );

    if (is_array($menu))
    {
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach( $menu as $key=>$row )
            {
                echo '<li>'.$row.'</li>';
                if (is_array($submenu[$key]))
                {
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach( $submenu[$key] as $sub )
                    {
                        echo '<li>'.$sub.'</li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

---

**RESULTADO**

> Éxito time: 0.01 memory: 82880 signal:0
>
> - about
>   - about my name
>   - about my
>       location
> - news
> - search
>   - search
>       me